# Entity Framework 4 and ASP.NET MVC3 + Scaffolding Problems

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Recently I've been trying out the new .Net 4.0 toolchains for Visual Studio 2010, and the new Nuget Package Manager.  I've played with MVC3 a fair bit, and tried out the MVCScaffolding package, and was pretty impressed.  To close the loop, I decided to check out Entity Framework 4 to really get into the rapid prototyping funness.

Alas, I am not able to create a simple model with EF4, and successfully generate a usable scaffold from that structure.

The structure I have scoped down to at this point is an entity "Cake", with a primary key Id and a string FrostingColor.  After generating the sql and deploying it to the database, I generated the scaffold with MVCScaffolding.

Then, I compile and run, and attempt to visit my site/Cakes/Index page.  I receive the server error:

```
The type 'MvcApplication1.Models.Cake' is not a supported entity type.
```

I've spent a while googling for others with this problem, but can't make heads or tails of it.  Has anyone tried this, or happens to know what might be causing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible answer here: http://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/discussions/247163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best as I can understand at this point - the generated classes from the edmx cannot be used as an entity.  After installing the ADO.NET C# POCO Entity Generator and generating the appropriate POCO class for my "cake" entity, everything seems to work fine.  I'm still baffled by why the partial classes inheriting from "entityobject" can't be used as an entity, but at least have a workable solution to generate a quick prototype from a given database model.

Relevant Resources:

- [About EF4 and it's Evolution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx)
- [Using POCO Generators](http://daveswersky.com/2010/05/26/entity-framework-4-then-and-now/)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [MVC Music Store Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1). It uses EF CodeFirst and MVC3. You can also take a look at [MVC Scaffolding: Standard Usage](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/mvcscaffolding-standard-usage/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+SteveCodeville+%28Steve+%40+Codeville%29&utm_content=Google+Feedfetcher)

Comment: Thanks for the links. They are both better than the slightly less detailed tutorials I had been following.